# Use set acessor during JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Let's say I have an instance of a class like this which I want to serialize to JSON:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { }

    private List<string> texts;
    public List<string> Texts
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> { "You got me!" };
        }
        set
        {
            texts = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Setting property!");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to to make sure the set accessor for "Texts" is called during deserialization, i.e make sure that the private property "texts" in MyClass gets set. However, if I run a small test case:

```
public void TestMyClass()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    var jsonBefore = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
    var jsonAfter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonBefore);
}
```

The set method never gets called, i.e private "texts" is null after deserialization. How can I make sure that the set accessor in public "Texts" gets called during deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reason is because you use newtonsoft json serializer that is quite different from built in .net one.

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myClass);
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
```

This code is going to work fine.

The second reason is in your get property and how it's processed by newtonsoft json serializer, you have default list creating (it is better to put it into constructor as as it made now doesn't make any sense)

If you still want to use your get as it implemented now, use JsonSerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling setting for customizing object creating,

```
var jsonBefore = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
var jsonAfter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonBefore,  new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set null in `Texts` property then you can set default value to it.
Like  `private List<string> texts = new List<string>(){ "Default Value" };`

and instead of

```
get
{
    return new List<string> { "You got me!" };
}
```

you should use

```
get
{
    return texts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (in our case it's json).

Object state consists of fields values, all methods or other behavioral logic is  simply ignored.

Properties are basically methods that work with backing fields so they're not used on serialization / deserialization because they do not represent object's state.

In our case field `texts` is serialized with use of reflection. Then it is deserialized directly and it is possible that serializer doesn't even know that property exists.